# Dynamic creation of test cases

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I have a JSON file containing multiple test cases like so:

```json
{
    "cases":[
        {
            "case": "TestCas1",
            "input": "x=y",
            "result": {
                "type": "Eq",
                "lhs": "x",
                "rhs": "y"
            }
        },
        { 
        //etc
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to generate rougly something like:

```cs
   [Test]
   [TestCase("x=y", "x", "y", "Eq")]
   /// Other test cases from file go here.
   public void Test(string input, string lhs, string rhs, string op)
```

Now, I know how to parse and process the file, and how to write the test, but how do I generate TestCases based on the processed data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `TestCaseSourceAttribute` pointing to a method that generates test cases. There are several ways to use it described in the documentation. The following is typical...

```cs
public class MyTestFixture
{
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(MyTestCases))]
    public void MyTestMethod(string input, string lhs, string rhs, string op)
    {
        // Your test code here
    }

    static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> MyTestCases()
    {
        foreach (var item in your json file) // pseudocode
        {
            // Get the four argument values

            yield return new TestCaseData(input, lhs, rhs, op);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this does answer my question. But what if I wanted to have multiple JSON files?

Comment: Then you would either read multiple files in one source or have multiple sources. The latter is preferable if some tests need different combinations of sources. Of course, each test can have more than one `TestCaseSourceAttribute` if needed.